# How to write angular search box and attach to an api?

Tags: javascript, angular, spring-boot, filter

I have this api that does server-side filters and it works well. I tested it using postman. I am new to angular and I would like to add a search box and do the filter from the UI.

This is the api:

```
http://localhost:8080/tetype/all/{keyword}
```

I have this in my component's TypeScript file:

```
 onSubmit() {
    const url = `http://localhost:8080/tetype/all/${this.keyword}`;
    this.http.get<string[]>(url).subscribe(results => {
      this.searchResults = results;
    });
  }

  clearSearch() {
    this.keyword = '';
    this.searchResults = [];
  }
```

and this in my component's HTML template:

```
<form #searchForm (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
  Filter: <input type="text" name="keyword" size="50"[(ngModel)]="keyword" required>
  <button type="submit" (click)="onSubmit()">   Search    </button>
  <button type="button" (click)="clearSearch()">Clear</button>
</form>

<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let result of searchResults">{{result}}</li>
</ul>
```

I am able to see the search box and everything but the filtering logic is not working. I am 100 sure the API gives the correct result.

I tried the above code and it is not working.

Comment: The component's TypeScript code is the code from the  HTML-template (written twice). Please write down the TypeScript code.

Comment: Your `const url` in the `onSubmit()`-method have a typo: `…8080/tetype/all…`

Comment: can you show us your results from api in console?

Comment: What you are getting in console....we need to know...like if you are getting some error or what? Please try to log the console and let us know the response

Answer (score 0):

First add the `keyword` parameter to your `onSubmit` method so that you can filter by keyword:

```js
onSubmit(keyword) {
  const url = `http://localhost:8080/tetype/all/${keyword}`;
  this.http.get<string[]>(url).subscribe(results => {
    this.searchResults = results;
  });
}
```

Then in your html call this function from the input:

```html
<input type="text" name="keyword" size="50"[(ngModel)]="keyword" (input)="onSubmit(keyword)" required>
```

**In case** this approach doesn't work with you, you can also check this [solution](https://angular.io/start/start-forms) in the official docs.